# Get max or min of parameter to row value postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

For a parameterized postgresql query, how can I return either the value in the row or the parameter provided.

I have a table (we will call it `foo`) with three columns: `id`, `maximum`, `minimum`

I want to select the rows so that the max and min will have a ceiling or a floor that I provide them.  Directly in postgresql I would be able to select like this:

```
SELECT
   id,
   GREATEST(minimum, 5),
   LEAST(maximum, 10)
FROM foo
```

So this will return only values between 5 and 10 for each row.

However when converting this to use in my php code:

```
$floor = 5;
$ceiling = 10;
$query = 'SELECT id, GREATEST(minimum, $2), LEAST(maximum, $1) FROM foo';
$parameters = [ $ceiling, $floor];
$result = pg_query_params($query, $parameters);
```

This doesn't work because parameters need to be in the `WHERE` clause of the query.  How do I write the query so that I am able to pass in the parameters properly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Heredoc:

```
$floor = 5;
$ceiling = 10;

$query = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    id, 
    GREATEST(minimum, $floor),
    LEAST(maximum, $ceiling)
FROM 
    foo
SQL;

$result = pg_query_params($query);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: However that means that I lose the protection from sql injection from using parameters.

Comment: Are the values provided by users, or are they fixed?

Comment: Provided by users. My question was using integers but I also want to know more generally. If i need to do something similar using strings for example. I can't use `intval` then like in my example.

Comment: Hmm. My answer isn't safe, then. Sorry!